# Writing vector in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, vector

How do you write a vector in OpenCV? Using HoughlinesP, the lines are of type `Vector<Vec4i>` and holds values [x1,y1,x2,y2]. How do I make my own vector? I tried

```
vector<Vec4i> line;
```

`line[0] = [1,2,3,4];`

and it doesn't work with the error 'expected an identifier. Please advice, thank you.

Comment: I think you should study more about vectors.

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<Vec4i> line;

line.push_back(Vec4i(1,2,3,4));
line.push_back(Vec4i(5,6,7,8));
```

Comment: what if I want to write it into a particular array say line[1]?

Comment: you mean: `vector<Vec4i> line(100); /*line has 100 Vec4i now*/ line[1] = Vec4i(6,5,4,3);` ?    for more on vectors, have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Answer (score 1):

see dis: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#vec .

```
typedef Vec<uchar, 2> Vec2b;
typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;
typedef Vec<uchar, 4> Vec4b;

typedef Vec<short, 2> Vec2s;
typedef Vec<short, 3> Vec3s;
typedef Vec<short, 4> Vec4s;

typedef Vec<int, 2> Vec2i;
typedef Vec<int, 3> Vec3i;
typedef Vec<int, 4> Vec4i;

typedef Vec<float, 2> Vec2f;
typedef Vec<float, 3> Vec3f;
typedef Vec<float, 4> Vec4f;


typedef Vec<float, 6> Vec6f;

typedef Vec<double, 2> Vec2d;
typedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d;
typedef Vec<double, 4> Vec4d;
typedef Vec<double, 6> Vec6d;
```

now you know !

Comment: the link http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#vec  is not working